# Windows Task Scheduler doesn't allow for whitespaces

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

When creating a new task and selecting the file to be executed via the file browser, it automatically encloses the path in double quotes but this does not work. How do I deal with whitespaces in the path for Task Scheduler?

For example: `C:\Users\Fisher Man\Desktop\script.bat` automatically gets converted to `"C:\Users\Fisher Man\Desktop\script.bat"`. This still doesn't work as I still get a `C:\Users\Fisher` does not exist error with `Man\Desktop\script.bat` being taken as an argument.

Edit: I'm trying to run a python script using venv, to keep it simple I've placed the commands in a .bat script:

```
 cd "C:\Users\Fisher Man\Desktop\Program\"
.env\Scripts\python.exe main.py
```

Currently bypassing using the script with the following answer.

### Solution:

> open cmd & change to C:\Users. Type dir /x. Look at the center column
> (with the ~ tilde) for your short name. It will probably be FISHER~1.
> Use this name instead in your path.
> C:\Users\fisher~1\Desktop\script.sh

*-Señor CMasMas*

Comment: Please include in your post enough of the script to see how it handles its parameter, and also the command you use to execute it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since when do `.sh` Unix shell files run on Windows?

Comment: Just a comment, but having a space in your username is going to make your life slightly miserable for years to come. spaces in path elements are just problematic, period. not that you can't work around it, but the minor headaches will just keep coming. ask yourself if you are getting any value out of having a space in your username. I'd guess that you aren't.

Comment: @FrankThomas is not wrong.. prepare for misery.. but I can probably help.  See if the short name is supported.  open cmd & change to C:\Users.  Type `dir /x`.  Look at the center column (with the ~ tilde) for your short name.  It will probably be `FISHER~1`.  Use this name instead in your path.  `C:\Users\fisher~1\Desktop\script.sh`

Comment: @FrankThomas I definitely could do without it, I usually code on a mac which doesn't have a whitespace in its user so I never had this issue. I'm just running the script on a Windows machine. Definitely going to avoid spaces if I end up formatting this PC.

Comment: @Appleoddity I was initially running it off git's bash emulation. I ended up switching to a .bat script anyway.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks for the help, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Your problem may be the way the handler for .sh files is implemented in the registry. Perhaps the quotes are missing there. So task scheduler does pass the parameter properly to the file handler, but then it is treated as two separate parameters. Look in `HKCR\.sh`